Retrieving qubit specifications and gate errors for legacy jobs?
I want to retrieve "metadata" for some jobs I ran in qiskit a long time ago (goes back a time span of approximately 2 years). I'm interested in the qubit characterizations and the gates errors, basically, everything that appears in the device card in IBM webpage.
Until a couple of months back, everything worked with the old commands
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()

but now these have became obsolete, for which I used
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
provider = IBMProvider()

However, these no longer work in retrieving the data I'm interested, e.g.
print(retrieve_job.properties())

returns None. Any idea how to access this data?
